# Background-Size: Multiple Values with inherit first

Tags: html, css

my Question ist about background-size. I wanne use with multiple values.

My Css Code is like this

```
background-image: url("../img/redlinie.png"), url("../img/umkleidekabine.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x, no-repeat;
background-size: initial, cover
```

For the first image redlinie.png i need no sizing at all. I just need sizing for the 2nd PNG. But here the Problem. It seems that it isnt allowed to have inheritor initial to be the first value?

Is there some kind of "trick" that i can set multiple background images with no background-size for the first png, but with contain for the 2nd PNG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `inherit` and `initial` keywords must appear alone. They cannot be used even in a comma-separated list of values.

There isn't a way to omit a component value and have the browser interpret it as an initial value, since `background-size` isn't a shorthand property, just a property that accepts multiple comma-separated values. Omitting any trailing values causes the browser to [reuse](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering) the values that *are* specified, rather than the initial value.

Since [the initial value of `background-size` is `auto`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size), you can simply specify that:

```
background-size: auto, cover
```